# Drawing a recursive snow flake

Tags: java, recursion

I have this problem where I have to draw a recursive snow flake such that the flake has 6 lines coming from a center point, each 60 degrees apart from one another, then the endpoint of each of those lines, is the center point of another flake. Each time it branches off to another flake, the length is cut in half. The length is defined as just one side of the flake. This recursion continues to happen until the length is down to a distance such as 20 pixels where you can no longer distinguish the different flakes.

I understand that recursion is just a method that calls itself, but I'm just having difficulty setting up this problem. What I've got so far is the math to draw the initial flake but I just don't know how to set up the recursion to draw the flakes.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SnowFlake extends JPanel {

    private MainWindow panel;
    private int x1OfFlake = 400;
    private int y1OfFlake = 400;
    private int maxLength = 200;  // this is length of, 1 0f 6 branches for each individual flake

    public SnowFlake() {
        // generateRandCoodinatesLength();
    }

    public void generateRandCoodinatesLength() {
        Random rn = new Random();
        maxLength = rn.nextInt(200) + 100;
        x1OfFlake = rn.nextInt(700) + 100;
        y1OfFlake = rn.nextInt(700) + 100;
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        drawFlake(levels, x1OfFlake, y1OfFlake, g);  // x1, y1, x2, y2
    }

    public void drawFlake(int level, int x1, int y1, Graphics g){
        //below was just how I made sure my picture was correct
        /*
          g.drawLine(x1, y1, 600, 400); //1
          g.drawLine(x1, y1, 500, 227); //2
          g.drawLine(x1, y1, 300, 227); //3
          g.drawLine(x1, y1, 200, 400); //4
          g.drawLine(x1, y1, 300, 573); //5
          g.drawLine(x1, y1, 500, 573); //6
        */
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + maxLength, y1);  // 1
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + (maxLength / 2), y1 - ((int) ((maxLength / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 2
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - (maxLength / 2), y1 - ((int) ((maxLength / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 3
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - maxLength, y1); // 4
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - (maxLength / 2), y1 + ((int) ((maxLength / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 5
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + (maxLength / 2), y1 + ((int) ((maxLength / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 6
    }
}
```

This is what the end result should kind of look like, except with more branches drawn.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lhag.jpg)

Comment: The important part of recursion is establishing the one or more base cases which will terminate the recursion. This would be the min size limit you spoke of. Based on the idea, you'll need to call `drawFlake` for each end of each line created. Draw the line, then call drawFlake on each of it's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could bring you closer to what you want

```
public void drawFlake(int level, float angleDegrees, Graphics g) {
    /* 
     * Exit condition
     * If the max number of levels has been reached, 
     * or the maxLength is no longer visible when drawn
     */
    if (level >= MAX_LEVEL || maxLength == 0) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     * Secondary condition, increment the level if we've gone around the 
     * circle once
     */
    if (angleDegrees >= 360) {
        maxLength *= .9;
        drawFlake(level + 1, 0, g);
        return;
    }

    g.drawLine(
        centerX,
        centerY,
        centerX + (int) (maxLength * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleDegrees))),
        centerY + (int) (maxLength * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleDegrees))));

    int currentLevelAngleIncrement = 60 / (level + 1);
    drawFlake(level, angleDegrees + currentLevelAngleIncrement, g);
}
```

Ends up something like this..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what level is - doesn't appear to be used in the drawFlake method...

I would change your recursive function to take the x and y coordinates and the length of the current line:

```
public void drawFlake(int x1, int y1, int length, Graphics g) {
    // draw the current flake - exactly the same as your method except that it
    // uses the length passed not the maximum length
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + length, y1);  // 1
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + (length / 2), y1 - ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 2
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - (length / 2), y1 - ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 3
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - length, y1); // 4
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - (length / 2), y1 + ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 5
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + (length / 2), y1 + ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 6

    // recursion
    int newLength = length / 2;
    if (newLength >= MIN_LENGTH) {
        // this is the recursive bit - call the function again for each of the end points
        drawFlake(x1 + length, y1, newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 + (length / 2), y1 - ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))), newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 - (length / 2), y1 - ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))), newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 - length, y1, newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 - (length / 2), y1 + ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))), newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 + (length / 2), y1 + ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))), newLength, g);
    }
}
```

Then just kick it off with the start values:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    drawFlake(x1OfFlake, y1OfFlake, maxLength, g);
}
```

Note that the coordinates passed to the recursive `drawFlake` methods are the same as the end points of the `drawLine` calls, so you could calculate these once and reuse them.

Also, for readability (and maybe performance), I'd just calculate `(length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3)` once at the start of each call.

Haven't run it, so may be some typos, but should get you on the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, the code below helped a lot with the recursion. It makes more sense now that I have to pass those variables into the method so they are actually changing. Also with this, I noticed that if you only divide the length by two it just forms a hexagonal shape, filled with triangles. So messing around with that and the minimum length solved that problem.

```
    public void drawFlake(int x1, int y1, int length, Graphics g){


    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + length, y1);  // 1
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + (length / 2), y1 - ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 2
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - (length / 2), y1 - ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 3
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - length, y1); // 4
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 - (length / 2), y1 + ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 5
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1 + (length / 2), y1 + ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))));  // 6

    //recursion
    int newLength = length/3; //changed this to 3 to make it more look more like a flake

    if(newLength >= minLength){
        drawFlake(x1 + length, y1, newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 + (length / 2), y1 - ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))), newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 - (length / 2), y1 - ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))), newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 - length, y1, newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 - (length / 2), y1 + ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))), newLength, g);
        drawFlake(x1 + (length / 2), y1 + ((int) ((length / 2) * Math.sqrt(3))), newLength, g);
    }
```